# Hoare Partition is not correct?

Tags: python, algorithm, quicksort

I'm python to implement Hoare Partition. The code is as following,which is pretty straight-forward.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

def partition(li,start,end):
    print li
    x=li[start]
    i=start-1
    j=end+1
    while True:
        while True:
            j-=1
            if x>=li[j]:
                break

        while True:
            i+=1
            if x<=li[i]:
                break   
        if i<j:
            li[i],li[j]=li[j],li[i]
            print "i:",i
            print "j:",j
            print li
        else:
            return j

def main():
    li=[13,19,9,5,12,8,7,4,11,2,6,21] 
    print partition(li,0,11)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

but I do not get the right answer. The output is something like:`[6, 2, 9, 5, 12, 8, 7, 4, 11, 19, 13, 21]`
and j=8, because `li[j]=11` and there is still an 12 in the middle of the list. When I manually run this program, I got the same result.

Have I missed something that make the partition function works wrong?

Comment: What output were you expecting?

Comment: I want to get right j which makes every element in li[start:j] less than element in li[j:end].for example:li=[6, 2, 9, 5, 12, 8, 7, 4, 11, 13, 19, 21] and j=9